# Get two input values in one hidden input jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get two values first and last names in one hidden field with space between. I tried with this code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input[name="firstname"]').keyup(function() {
    $('input[name="fullname"]').val($(this).val());
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input[name="lastname"]').keyup(function() {
    $('input[name="fullname"]').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
<input type="text" name="lasttname" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="fullname" value="">
```

It is not working how i want. It's showing only one value each time.
Can anyone help me with this how can i get this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as per your code, last name will replace first name

Comment: yes, it is happening.

Comment: just a note. You don't need two different $(document).ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're overwriting the value of the hidden field on every key entry. To fix this you can use a single event handler on both inputs which concatenates the first and lastnames together. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $firstname = $('input[name="firstname"]');
  var $lastname = $('input[name="lastname"]');
  var $fullname = $('input[name="fullname"]');

  $firstname.add($lastname).keyup(function() {
    $fullname.val($firstname.val() + ' ' + $lastname.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="firstname" value="" />
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="" /><br /><br />

<input type="text" name="fullname" value="" readonly="true" />
```

Note that I made the hidden field visible to make the behaviour clearer in the example.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

As of now you are overwriting the content of `hidden` input. You need to create the `fullname` string and then update the `hidden` input.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input[name="firstname"], input[name="lastname"]').keyup(function() {
    var fn = $('input[name="firstname"]'),
      ln = $('input[name="lastname"]');

    var name = fn.val() + ' ' + ln.val();

    $('input[name="fullname"]').val(name)
    console.clear()
    console.log(name)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="">

<input type="hidden" name="fullname" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize your variables with the jQuery objects to avoid repeated look over the DOM tree.
2. Concatenate the values to avoid losing the previously entered values.
3. The input which contains the lastName value, has a typo `lasttname`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $fn = $('input[name="fullname"]');
  var $firstName = $('input[name="firstname"]');
  var $lastName = $('input[name="lastname"]');

  $firstName.keyup(function() {
    $fn.val($(this).val() + " " + $lastName.val());
  });

  $lastName.keyup(function() {
    $fn.val($firstName.val() + " " + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="">

<input type="text" name="fullname" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the first name is some variable

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('input[name="firstname"]').keyup(function() {
     $('input[name="fullname"]').val($(this).val());
  });
  $('input[name="lastname"]').keyup(function() {
    var oldname = $('input[name="fullname"]').val(); //take firstname from hidden field
    $('input[name="fullname"]').val(oldname + ' '+$(this).val()); // appending the values
   });
});
```

Comment: What is the point of the `fname` variable? Plus this will just append the content every time a key is released which will not do what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You don't need 2 document.ready and 2 different even handler for keyup

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" data-name value="">
<input type="text" name="lasttname" data-name value="">

<input type="hidden" name="fullname" value="">


jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('[data-name]').keyup(function() {

    $('input[name="fullname"]').val($('input[name="lastname"]').val() + " " + 
    $('input[name="firstname"]').val());

    });       

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your code like given below:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
<input type="text" name="lasttname" value="">

<input type="hidden" name="fullname" value="">


jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('input[name="firstname"]').keyup(function() {
    if($('input[name="lastname"]').val() != '')
    {
        var last_name = $('input[name="lastname"]').val();
        $('input[name="fullname"]').val($(this).val()+' '+last_name);            
    }
    else{
        $('input[name="fullname"]').val($(this).val());
    }
});
});
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('input[name="lastname"]').keyup(function() {
    if($('input[name="firstname"]').val() != '')
    {
        var first_name = $('input[name="firstname"]').val();
        $('input[name="fullname"]').val($(this).val()+' '+first_name);            
    }
    else{
        $('input[name="fullname"]').val($(this).val());
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple it is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('input[name="firstname"], input[name="lastname"]').keyup(function() {
    $('input[name="fullname"]').val($('input[name="firstname"]').val() + ' ' + $('input[name="lastname"]').val());
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It shows only the one value each time because you overwrite the previous value of fullname every time .

One solution is to add specific id's for `firstName` and `lastName` and during `keyup` you can have something like

```
$('input[name="lastname"]').keyup(function() {
    var value = $("#firstNameID").val() + $("#lastNameID").val();
     $('input[name="fullname"]').val(value);
 });
```

i didnt test it but this is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use two `ready` functions, use one, and put both event listeners inside that one.
Your problem is that your not updating the hidden field with both the first name and last name, you're instead overwriting the `firstname` with the last name. Thus you must append the last name to the first name and vice versa:

Take a look at the fiddle bellow for a working example. (I have made the hidden field `text` just so you can see the output)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input[name="firstname"]').keyup(function() {
    $('input[name="fullname"]').val($(this).val() +" " +$('input[name="lasttname"]').val());
  });

  $('input[name="lasttname"]').keyup(function() {
    $('input[name="fullname"]').val($('input[name="firstname"]').val() + " " + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="" />
<input type="text" name="lasttname" value="" />

<input type="text" name="fullname" value="" />
```